# Как добавить id в конструктор

Tags: javascript, ооп, prototype

Как можно добавить id в конструктор?

```js
function ready() {
    
    function Rectangle(i, w, h, c) {
        this.id = i;
        this.width = w;
        this.height = h;
        this.color = c;
    }
    
    Rectangle.prototype.elemId = function() {
        return this.id = document.getElementById();
    }
    
    Rectangle.prototype.doublewidth = function() {
        return this.width * 2;
    }
    
    Rectangle.prototype.doubleheight = function() {
        return this.height * 2;
    }
    
    var oneRect = new Rectangle("elem", 300, 150, "green");
    
    oneRect.elemId().style.background = oneRect.color;
    oneRect.elemId().style.width = oneRect.doublewidth() + "px";
    oneRect.elemId().style.height = oneRect.doubleheight() + "px";
};

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", ready);
```

```html
<div id="elem"></div>
```

Comment: непонятно что должен делать код, и какая связь id и конструктора. Ты же уже передаешь `id` в конструктор

Comment: вопрос ставящий в тупик

Comment: Возможно правильный ответ тут: `Да, именно так`

Comment: Немного оффтопа. Если вы планируете изменять свойства прямоугольника через `style` - ваш объект будет устаревать с каждой такой операцией. Определите эти операции внутри класса.

Comment: Можно пожалуйста поподробнее немного о style :) я просто только начал изучать и немного не пойму о стилях что Вы написали

Comment: Rectangle.prototype.elemId = function() {
        return document.getElementById(this.id).style;
    }

Comment: Смотри, ты вручную меняешь `style.width`, но свойство объекта `this.width` никто не обновляет. Лучше сделать сеттер `setWidthDouble`, а в нём и DOM-элемент поменять, и свойство обновлённое сохранить.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`id` уже добавлен в ваш конструктор: `this.id = i`

Судя по всему, вы пытаетесь вернуть элемент по `id` в методе `elemId`:

```
Rectangle.prototype.elemId = function() {
    return document.getElementById(this.id);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

В том же конструкторе можете создать поле, где будет храниться ссылка на `html-объект`, потому что каждый раз вызывать `getElementById` не очень правильно

```
function ready() {

    function Rectangle(i, w, h, c) {
        this.id = i;
        this.width = w;
        this.height = h;
        this.color = c;
        //  ссылка на html объект
        this.elem = document.getElementById(i);
    }

    Rectangle.prototype.doublewidth = function() {
        return this.width * 2;
    }

    Rectangle.prototype.doubleheight = function() {
        return this.height * 2;
    }

    var oneRect = new Rectangle("elem", 300, 150, "green");

    oneRect.elem.style.background = oneRect.color;
    oneRect.elem.style.width = oneRect.doublewidth() + "px";
    oneRect.elem.style.height = oneRect.doubleheight() + "px";
};

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", ready);
```

Comment: Хороший совет, однако хочу заметить, что вот именно `getElementById` один из самых оптимизированных методов работы с DOM. Его вполне себе можно вызывать повторно.

Answer (score 0):

Пример реализации через сеттеры(описал только ширину для простоты):

```js
function Rectangle(id, w, h, color) {
  var el = document.getElementById(id);
  el.style.width = w + 'px';
  el.style.height = h + 'px';
  el.style.backgroundColor = color;

  Object.defineProperty(this, "width", { 
    set: function (width) { 
      w = width;
      el.style.width = w + 'px';
    },
    get: function() {return w = parseFloat(el.style.width);}
  });
}

var r = new Rectangle('rect', 25, 50, 'red');
setTimeout(() => r.width*=2, 5e2);
setTimeout(() => r.width*=2, 10e2);
setTimeout(() => r.width*=2, 15e2);
```

```html
<div id="rect"></div>
```

Comment: спасибо, теперь стало понятно

Comment: А ты же знаешь, что в текущем виде в твоем коде `new` необязателен. И если его убрать ничего не поменяется?

Comment: Не надо ничего убирать) Завтра мы поменяем реализацию, скажем на новомодный `class` =)

Comment: Тогда и работать будет по другому. В данном случае _Rectangle_ у тебя не конструктор, а обычная функция

Comment: @Grundy - любая функция - потенциальный конструктор. Но также любой конструктор - обычная функция. Функцию в конструктор превращает не использование `this`, а оператор `new`. Оператор `new` хорошо описывает поведение с функциями, как эта. Что не так? Что именно по вашему будет работать по другому?

Comment: @vp_arth, если функция не создает объект своего типа - это не конструктор. И если ты сделаешь `r instanceof Rectangle` в своем коде, будет выведено `false`. То что используется `new` еще не делает функцию конструктором

Comment: Ок, победил. Так лучше?

Comment: ну хотя бы так.